# Using Skype for Business in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

For our company's chat we are using Skype for Business. The sidebar is currently accessible from the Outlook web app:

[image]
Can we have this button visible in SharePoint too? Or is there a better way to integrate them, like a Web Part or code to load Skype in a SharePoint page?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately as of this moment, you can't customize the Suite bar to show the SfB button.

The only option you have is OneDrive for Business and Sites.

If you have Office 365 Education subscription, then you can show OneNote Class Notebooks and OneNote staff notebooks.

Below is the screenshot of the SharePoint settings page.

Url would be - https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx

Login to this site using Tenant/SharePoint admin credentials to control the settings.

[image]

Reference - [Customize the suite bar in Office 365 for SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-navigation-in-SharePoint-Online-d5e8dc9a-73f8-45e4-93b4-8e55b546a5af?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)